# how to forbid dialog show in the windows taskbar in Qt programming when I open a new dialog?

Tags: c++, qt, dialog

how to forbid dialog show in the windows taskbar in Qt programming when I open a new dialog? 
when I open a new a dialog in the main window.In the windows taskbar always show a new dialog task,I don't want it shows. how to do it?

Comment: Did you set the main window as a parent for your dialog?

Comment: Please provide an [mcve] so that we can understand and help.

Answer (score 1):

Quoting from [QDialog](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qdialog.html):

> A dialog is always a top-level widget, but if it has a parent, its default location is centered on top of the parent's top-level widget (if it is not top-level itself). It will also share the parent's taskbar entry.
>   Use the overload of the QWidget::setParent() function to change the ownership of a QDialog widget.

- If Dialog's parent is set to None then it opens another window, and i have two entries in taskbar.
- If Dialog's parent is set to mainwindow - the dialog is shown inside the main window and share taskbar entry.